# Accessing Flask app running inside a Docker container

Tags: python, docker, flask, portforwarding

I have a Flask app that runs without errors if I run `python app.py` locally. It says `Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000`, and if I just go to `http://127.0.0.1:5000`, everything works like it's supposed to. The last line of `app.py` is `app.run(debug=True)`.

Now I'm trying to run this app using Docker. In my Dockerfile, one of the lines is `EXPOSE 8501`.

I then build the image with `docker build -t testimage .`

Finally I execute `docker run -it --expose=8501 -p 8501:8501 testimage`, and again it says `Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000`.

My questions is :what do I have to enter in my browser to access the app that is running inside the Docker container?

Answer (score 0):

You're exposing port 8501, but still run the flask app on port 5000. You should either start the app on exposed port (you can do that using `port` argument to `app.run`) or expose a different port when running docker, matching the one app runs on.

Comment: I didn't realize that ```port=5000``` is the default, thanks

Answer (score 0):

let's this is your flask server code

```
@app.route("/")
def home():
    response=f"Flask Server > Hello World : Flask in Docker. Current Time:{time.strftime('%B %d, %Y %I:%M:%S %p')}"
    log_file(response)
    return response

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host="0.0.0.0",debug=True,port=5000)
```

so flask app is running at port `5000`
now this is docker file

```
#run as main.py
CMD ["python","flask_server/app.py"]
```

now suppose you run `docker run -it -p 5002:5000 image_name` mapping port 5002 of the host(your machine) to port 5000 of docker. so on browser , open `http://127.0.0.1:5002/`
for more info, you can refer my [CICD repo](https://github.com/simpleappdesigner/CICD)

Comment: Adding both ```port=5000``` and ```host="0.0.0.0"``` did the trick!